# Displaying a Bootstrap Modal just once a Week with JQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get my modal only displayed once a week. This should be guilty for all pages the user visits on my homepage. The modal it self works just fine. But it appears each time I reload the page or go to another page.

Thanks a lot in advance!

For the cookie I use this:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Here is my code:

```js
// MODAL APPEAR AFTER 2 SECONDS
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#newsletter-modal').modal();
}, 2000);

// MODAL COOKIE FOR 7 DAYS

$(function() {
    if($.cookie('alreadyShow') === null) {
        $.cookie('alreadyShow', true, {expires: 7});

        $('#newsletter-modal').modal({
            display: 'block'
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/js.cookie.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="newsletter-modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h1 class="modal-title">Modal Headline</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Modal content goes here</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary newsletter-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default newsletter-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Just `console.log($.cookie('alreadyShow'))` before checking for `null` and see what value you get at first?

Comment: I added console.log($.cookie('alreadyShow')) and the Console just gives me "null"... My jQuery knowledge is limited so I don't know what to do with this information....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Timeout for your modal gets set every time the page is loaded, regardless of the cookie settings. Try moving that block into the function where you set the cookie. That way, it only gets called when a cookie doesn't already exist.

```
// MODAL COOKIE FOR 7 DAYS
$(function() {
    if($.cookie('alreadyShow') === null) {
        // MODAL APPEAR AFTER 2 SECONDS
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#newsletter-modal').modal();
        }, 2000);

        $.cookie('alreadyShow', true, {expires: 7});

        $('#newsletter-modal').modal({
            display: 'block'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply. Your answer is the solution! :)